# Is it possible to redirect a URL at a certain datetime via IIS (web.config)?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need a redirect that activates at a certain date at midnight. Is it possible to implement that via url rewrite? I mean as xml in web.config? How?

Answer (score 0):

No because you cannot know if there will be any traffic that could be redirected at that precise time. What you need to do is write a separate process (it could be as simple as some VBScript or Javascript that gets triggered by a Task Scheduler job) which would make the request at the specified time.